# How to use html type="date" for count in sql for number of student enrolled in a year?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a problem on how to count number of students in a year enroll?

My "Datefilled" is from html type="Date"

```
'Select Datefilled, count(Datefilled) as number_of_enrolled from studentinformation group by Datefilled'
```

but the problem I cant count for year total of student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume date format from HTML input type=date is yyyy-mm-dd. Regardless if your database field type is datetime or varchar, you can use function `year()` plus `group by` to aggregate records like this statement:

```
select year(Datefilled) year, count(Datefilled) number_of_enrolled 
from studentinformation
group by year(Datefilled);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extract mysql function for this

```
SELECT Datefilled, COUNT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Datefilled)) AS number_of_enrolled
FROM studentinformation 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Datefilled);
```

Read more at:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract